# Organizing models/controllers and classes in rails in subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working in a Rails project in which i have used the below names for model/controller and class files

```
/app/models/friends/friend.rb
/app/controllers/friends/friends_controller.rb
/lib/classes/friends/friend.rb
```

I tried to add all the models, controllers and class files in autoload path in application.rb.
But i am facing issues since the class names are same.

How should i handle this? and organize files in such a way that files are organized with name spaces.

Thanks,
Balan

Comment: Can you share classes also?

Answer (score 1):

A much better approach would be to use [Rails Engines](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html) & divide your app in isolated modules.

```
rails plugin new friends --full --mountable --dummy-path spec/dummy
```

the above command will generate a full mountable engine with isolated namespace, meaning that all the controllers and models from this engine will be isolated within the namespace of the engine. For instance, the `Post` model later will be called `Friends::Post`, and not simply `Post`. to mount this app inside your main rails app, you need do two things:

Add entry to Gemfile

```
gem 'friends', path: "/path/to/friends/engine"
```

And then add route to config/routes.rb

```
mount Friends::Engine, at: "/friends"
```

For more information on this approch, checkout:

- [Rails Guide to Engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)
- [Taming Rails Apps with Engines](http://blog.socialcast.com/taming-rails-apps-with-engines/)
- [RailsCast #277 Mountable Engines](http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines)

Answer (score 0):

The class names are same but path's are different, and you don't need to add classes to autoload except `/lib/classes/friends/friend.rb`

Did you tried the following way:

```
# app/models/friends/friend.rb
class Friends::Friends
  #...
end
# Friends::Friends.new

# app/controllers/friends/friends_controller.rb
class Friends::FriendsController < ApplicationController
  #...
end

# lib/classes/friends/friend.rb
module Classes
  module Friends
    class Friends
      #...
    end
  end
end
# Classes::Friends::Friends.new
```

To add lib files to autoload add following to your `applicaion.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```